# Xubuntu 23:10 integrated webcam

Tags: xubuntu, webcam, integrated

Ive recently noticed that after an upgrade (possibly the 23:04 -> 23:10 upgrade) my xubuntu 23:10 install no longer detects my integrated webcam.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which? Please [edit] with `lspci` and `lsusb` with both the current 23.10 and on a 23.04 LiveCD where it works. Are there messages in `dmesg` related to it about errors on 23.10 or successes on 23.04?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.